# Make elements in Row stay at space between and if they are too big wrap them

Tags: flutter

I want to make elements stay at space between if they don't overflow but if they do wrap them.

This is my code:

```
return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      if (constraints.maxWidth <= MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5) {
        return Wrap(
          children: [
            Text("very long text"),
            Text("2"),
          ],
        );
      } else {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
          children: [
            Text("short text"),
            Text("2"),
          ],
        );
      }
    },
  );
```

It is always entering in the wrap even if the text is small

Comment: try to use `alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween`

Comment: I tried that. It could not make it work properly. Could you put a link to a working code in an example of that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text('very long text'),
            Text("another text"),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 16),
        Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text('verylongtext' * 3),
            Text("another text"),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]